# Animate pulsing effect using CSS3 Transform Scale and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transform

I'm attempting to create a pulsing animation of an element using CSS3's `transform: scale(x,y)`. I want the object to endlessly pulse (becoming slightly larger) unless it's hovered over - at which point the current animation should finish (i.e. return to its original size) and cease pulsing until it's no longer being hovered over. I can't even seem to get jQuery's `.animate()` to work, however.

```
function pulse() {
  $('#pulsate').animate({
    transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out',
    transform:  'scale(1.05,1.05)'
  }, 1500, function() {
    $('#pulsate').animate({
      transition: 'all 1s ease-in-out',
      transform:  'scale(1,1)'
      }, 1500, function() {
        pulse();
    });
  });
}
pulse();
```

Would using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` be better here?  `.removeClass` would do the trick for stopping the animation on `.hover()`, but I'm unsure on implementation overall.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g4zC7/ ? Chrome only

Comment: Actually, yes, precisely like that. Except I'd like it to work in other browsers (at the very least Firefox). Very impressive that this is all CSS, though.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/g4zC7/2/ . I test Firefox 26 and IE 11.

Comment: That's crazy awesome, and thank you for teaching me it's possible with pure CSS. Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it. I actually ended up going with jQuery.transit though: https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations).

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
     transform: scale(1, 1);
    }

    50% {
     transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }

    100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

#test {
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    };
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    };
}

#test {
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}
#test:hover {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/g4zC7/2/